# Jquery click automation with delay?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, automation, click

I'm trying to make jquery script that clicks all elements from class (with delay - setTimeout) when the checkbox is checked and you click button 'automatic send' , but somthing is going wrong and it does not work :( 
Here is my code HTML/PHP code:

```
<td class="send_div">
    <a class="meilsend" href ="smtp/send.php?name='.$result['name'].'&ref='.$result['refnummer'].'&invoice_number='.$result['invoice_number'].'&insurance='.$result['insurance'].'">Send mail</a>
    <a class="fastsend" href="#" style="display: none;">Fast mail</a>
    <a class="fastsend2" href="smtp/fastsend.php?name='.$result['name'].'&ref='.$result['refnummer'].'&invoice_number='.$result['invoice_number'].'&insurance='.$result['insurance'].'" style="display: none;">Fast mail</a>
</td>

<th>
    Send mail  
    Fast Mode<input id="fastmode" type="checkbox" name="fastmode" value="1">
    <span style="display: none; cursor: pointer;" id="automatic">Automatic send</span>
</th>
```

This is my jquery

```
$('input[type=checkbox]#fastmode').on('click',function () {
    if ($('#fastmode').is(':checked')) {
       alert('You turn fast mode ON!');
       $('.meilsend').hide();
       $('.fastsend').show();
       $('#automatic').show();

      //START AUTOMATIC



      //END AUTOMATIC

      //AJAX
       $('.fastsend').on('click', function (){                      
        var fastsend = 'send';
        var fasthref = $(this).parent().find('.fastsend2').attr('href');
        $.ajax({
        url: fasthref,
        method: "POST",
        data: {fastsend:fastsend}, 
        success: function(data) 
        {
            $('#serachresult').fadeIn();
            $('#serachresult').html(data);          
        }       
        });   
        });
        // END AJAX

    } else {
        alert('You turn fast mode OFF!');
        $('.meilsend').show();
        $('.fastsend').hide()
        $('#automatic').hide()
    }  
}); `
```

Comment: "something is going wrong" - can you explain the error you are having?

Comment: when i type this $('#automatic').click(function(){
    $('.fastsend2').click();
   }); between // start and end automatic, i have no changes, i want when i click $('#automatic') to trigger all <a href with class $('#fastsend') because they transfer data with ajax and they have #fastsend2 url

Comment: Do you need to click with delay because the ajax requests are not complete and you get some error?

Answer (score 1):

Did you debug your code? F12 and so on... 
Can you format your answer (edit it)... I am getting blind trying to read the first part of your code (if something...)... :P

Anyway, Try this, for the Ajax call:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: fasthref,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: "{ 'fastsend': fastsend}",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                $('#serachresult').fadeIn();
                $('#serachresult').html(data);
            }     
            error: function (ex) {
                // DO YOUR STUFF
            }
        });
```